# Pandas unexpectedly rounding column when being read from postgres table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a postgres table and am reading it into a dataframe as follows:

```
def get_sql_engine():
    import sqlalchemy

    db_conn_info = get_conn_info()

    engine_string = '{db_type}://{user}:{password}@{server}:{port}/{database}'.format(
    db_type=db_conn_info['databasetype'],
    user=db_conn_info['username'],
    password=db_conn_info['password'],
    server=db_conn_info['server'],
    port=db_conn_info['port'],
    database=db_conn_info['databasename']
    )

    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sql_engine = get_sql_engine()
    agingar = pd.read_sql_table('agingar', sql_engine)
```

In the postgres table, the number in the "Orig Inv Amt" column is 11,273.1602.  The column datatype is float4.  When I read the table into a dataframe, I the number in this column turns to 11273.2 .  I tried using the coerce_float=False with no luck.  Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: Which db api are you using -`psycopg2`? Please include it in engine_string.